# Kubernetes rc sent args to container app

Tags: docker, kubernetes

**question:**
I have a cluster run by k8s,and I run a app by rc.yaml.  My app need a args id(unique),setup id in rc.yaml.

```
args:
   - -id
   - ip-172-31-31-205.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal-2
```

if I setup replicas=2,how to control the id is different.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`ConfigMap`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/user-guide/configmap) type that's being added to the new version of Kubernetes being released this month.

Comment: Until then, you can stick your configuration into secrets, as is done in https://github.com/kelseyhightower/conf2kube.